# How do I specify the python version with a cpp project in Travis CI?

Tags: python, travis-ci

I need to test a python script against both python 2 and 3 against mac and linux, I've got the following configuration:

```
os:
  - linux
  - osx

language: cpp

osx_image: xcode8.2

compiler:
  - clang

script:
  - clang --version
  - bash run-tests.sh
```

How do I add each python version to the matrix to create 4 jobs?

Answer (score -1):

Assuming you can set up your run-tests.sh to pick up and use the python version from some environment variable `PY`:

```
os:
  - linux
  - osx

language: cpp

osx_image: xcode8.2

compiler:
  - clang

matrix:
  include:
    - env: PY=/path/to/your/first/python
    - env: PY=/path/to/your/second/python

script:
  - clang --version
  - bash run-tests.sh
```